# Is deleting the Qur'an from a computer prohibited?

Tags: quran, digital-files

I know it is forbidden to burn or desecrate the Qur'an in anyway and we must treat it with utmost respect.

Is deleting the Qu'ran from a computer the same as burning the Qur'an? What is the difference?
If my college friend sees the Qur'an on my computer and deletes it in malice, then is he committing a sin?

Answer (score 4):

Digital copies of the Qur'an, according to the majority opinion, are not considered to be manuscripts (mus-haf) of the Qur'an, and therefore the ruling of touching (opening) or getting rid of them (deleting) does not apply. In either case though, it is hard to see how deleting a file would count as desecrating it. There are obviously situations in which Qur'ans will need to be disposed of. In that case, they are either buried, shredded, or even burned, ironically enough. This doesn't count as being disrespectful, unless of course the *intention* is to disrespect it.

Comment: If my friend had the malice in his voice when he deleted it on my computer. Like said 'i'm deleting the Qar'an, watch me do it! hahaha' what view point should i take?

Comment: I'd take the viewpoint that disrespecting your beliefs doesn't sound very friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware of the definition of destroying (as in a physical product) and deletion of a softcopy (as in a computer file).  The end result is the "removal" from existence.

There are stated methods of destroying physical product.

With the soft copies, the removal is quick but as Mr. Ansari pointed out previously, the intention, in this case, plays a role. If there is malice while removing then that person is being disrespectful. Conversely, if the removal is by "you" and you simply do not require the copy anymore than there is no harm. Again, the intention is at play.