# Is it prohibited to send Quranic verses by WhatsApp where people delete it after reading it?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, technology

Is it prohibited to send Quranic verses by WhatsApp where people delete it after reading it?

Comment: No... Where did you get the claim from?

Comment: Could you explain the issue in this question? People delete verses and what??... They will remain a recited quran as long as this life exists, so where is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting electronic verses of the Qur'an is not considered a big deal according to multiple fatawa.  An [Ask Imam fatwa](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/28478) sums up why nicely:

> When disposing of Quranic verses, the main objective is to protect the Quran from any form of disrespect. **Since deleting Quranic files off of a storage device is not tantamount to disrespecting the Quran, it will be permissible to do so.**

This is affirmed by [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=133004), Darul Ifta ([1](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Dua-Supplications/41397), [2](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Dawah--Tableeg/36271), [3](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/The-Holy-Quran/5592), [4](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/The-Holy-Quran/29260)), [Ask Mufti](http://askamufti.com/question-details.aspx?qstID=6630), [Islam Help Line](http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/8500), and an [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/164616) goes further an even encourages sharing the Qur'an electronically:

> There is nothing wrong with sending Qur’aanic messages via e-mail or SMS. Rather this is the kind of deed for which a person will be rewarded ...

[UAE news](http://www.thenational.ae/news/uae-news/fatwa-allows-quran-reading-on-smartphones) reports another fatwa encouraging it.

---

See also [Is deleting the Qur'an from a computer prohibited?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21361/17163) and [Can I delete Qur'an recitation audio clips from my phone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31037/17163), and [Tamer Shlash's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2097/17163) to [Is it permissible to use a digital version of the Holy Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2091/17163).  (However, none of these posts give references to this particular question.)